# Cannot get table data to decrease width

Tags: html, css

I cannot get a table row data (`td`) to decrease it's width. **The problem is that the avatar td seems to take up the majority of the entire row. I need the text with Traveler column to move to the left as shown**

Here is the current progress of what I have:

[image]

This is what it's supposed to look like.

[image]

**If you look, the gray container has text on the right side and text that should be directly next to the avatar image**

There is an established two columns of text **(that row is 3 table cells long)** The problem is that one of my `td`'s has a width that is causing the column starting with `Traveler` to be pushed so far right.

So here's my HTML:

```
<div id="reviews">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="reviewuserinfo">
        <td width="60px"><img class="avatar" src="/avatar/35274"/></td>
        <td>Traveler<br>posted on 15 May, 2008</td>
        <td align="right" style="padding-right:15px">Joined 2 years ago<br>12 reviews and 49 comments posted</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="reviewuserdata">

        <td style="width:100%" colspan="3">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="reviewchart">
                <tr><td><h2>Overall Rating <img class="stars" src="/stars/3.9/large" /> <span class="rating">4.5</span></h2></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel" style="padding-top:15px">QUALITY OF THE DANCERS</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">PRIVATE DANCES, VALUE FOR MONEY</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">OVERALL HOSPITALITY</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">GUEST TO DANCER RATIO</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">VARIETY OF DANCERS</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">VALUE FOR MONEY, COVER CHARGE</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">VALUE FOR MONEY, DRINKS</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">VALUE FOR MONEY, FOOD</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">OVERALL ATMOSPHERE</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">SOUND SYSTEM AND DJ</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
  </div>
```

And finally here's my CSS:

```
    @CHARSET "UTF-8";
    .page {
     position: relative;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     width: 1200px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
     border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;   
    }
    table {
     border:0px;
     width:100% 
    }
    table.reviewsouter .reviewleft{
     width:800px
    }
    table.reviewsouter .reviewright{
     width:400px
    }
    #reviewspotlight {
     position: relative;
     background-color:#000000;
     height:111px;
     z-index:19997;
     font-family: DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
     color:#ffffff;
    }
    #reviews {
      position: relative;
      background-color:#ffffff;
      color:#000000;
      border-right:1px solid #d0d0d0;
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo {
      background-color:#f0f0f0;
      height:60px;
      border-left:1px solid #d0d0d0;      
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo img.avatar{
      position:relative;
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
      margin:10px 0px 10px 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo div {
      display:block
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserdata {
      background-color:#ffffff;
      height: 315px;
      border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
      vertical-align: top;  
    }
    #reviews table td h2 {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:nowrap;
        font:24px/24px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
        margin:0px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        /**padding:20px 0px 9px 15px;*/
        /**padding-top:20px;*/
        /**padding-left:20px;*/
    }
    #reviews table td h2 img.stars {
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #reviews table td h2 span.rating{
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:145px;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#e85a06;
        font-weight:bold;   
    }

    table.reviewchart {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:nowrap;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font:14px/14px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
        margin:0px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        /**padding:20px 0px 9px 15px;*/
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-left:20px;  
    }
    table.reviewchart td.reviewlabel{
        /**padding-top:15px;*/
        padding-bottom:15px;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so i was able to fix the width position for the text by adding a `colspan of 3` however the word Traveler is pushed to the right still. I tried setting margins and paddings but that did not work.

Here is my current progress:

[image]

Comment: try changing `<td style="width:100%">` to `<td style="width:100%" colspan="3">`

Comment: @j08691 please see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late to the party, but yes, `colspan="3"` is needed.  Then, what you can do is add `width="1%"` to the cell with the image and update your css to have `margin: 10px;` instead of `margin: 10px 0 10px 10px;` for the image.  That should fix it.

```css
   .page {
     position: relative;
     background-color: #ffffff;
     width: 1200px;
     margin: 0px auto;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     border-left: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
     border-right: 1px solid #d0d0d0;   
    }
    table {
     border:0px;
     width:100% 
    }
    table.reviewsouter .reviewleft{
     width:800px
    }
    table.reviewsouter .reviewright{
     width:400px
    }
    #reviewspotlight {
     position: relative;
     background-color:#000000;
     height:111px;
     z-index:19997;
     font-family: DinWebCond, Sans-serif;
     color:#ffffff;
    }
    #reviews {
      position: relative;
      background-color:#ffffff;
      color:#000000;
      border-right:1px solid #d0d0d0;
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo {
      background-color:#f0f0f0;
      height:60px;
      border-left:1px solid #d0d0d0;      
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo img.avatar{
      position:relative;
      width:40px;
      height:40px;
      margin:10px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserinfo div {
      display:block
    }
    #reviews table tr.reviewuserdata {
      background-color:#ffffff;
      height: 315px;
      border-left:1px solid #ffffff;
      vertical-align: top;  
    }
    #reviews table td h2 {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:nowrap;
        font:24px/24px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
        margin:0px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        /**padding:20px 0px 9px 15px;*/
        /**padding-top:20px;*/
        /**padding-left:20px;*/
    }
    #reviews table td h2 img.stars {
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:10px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #reviews table td h2 span.rating{
        position:absolute;
        margin-left:145px;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#e85a06;
        font-weight:bold;   
    }

    table.reviewchart {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        white-space:nowrap;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font:14px/14px DinWebCond,Sans-serif;
        margin:0px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        /**padding:20px 0px 9px 15px;*/
        padding-top:20px;
        padding-left:20px;  
    }
    table.reviewchart td.reviewlabel{
        /**padding-top:15px;*/
        padding-bottom:15px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="reviews">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="reviewuserinfo">
        <td width="1%"><img class="avatar" src="/avatar/35274"/></td>
        <td>Traveler<br>posted on 15 May, 2008</td>
        <td align="right" style="padding-right:15px">Joined 2 years ago<br>12 reviews and 49 comments posted</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="reviewuserdata">
        <td style="width:100%" colspan="3">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="reviewchart">
                <tr><td><h2>Overall Rating <img class="stars" src="/stars/3.9/large" /> <span class="rating">4.5</span></h2></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel" style="padding-top:15px">QUALITY OF THE DANCERS</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">PRIVATE DANCES, VALUE FOR MONEY</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">OVERALL HOSPITALITY</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">GUEST TO DANCER RATIO</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">VARIETY OF DANCERS</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">VALUE FOR MONEY, COVER CHARGE</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">VALUE FOR MONEY, DRINKS</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">VALUE FOR MONEY, FOOD</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">OVERALL ATMOSPHERE</td></tr>
                            <tr><td class="reviewlabel">SOUND SYSTEM AND DJ</td></tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything after the column with the image is one big column . You're telling it to alight right so it's moving everything to the very right of that column. remove this or make it align="left" and it should fix your issue.

Comment: Is that not how you want it to look?

Comment: It is but the word Traveler is still pushed to the right a bit.

Comment: I did. The td that has a style of width 100% now has also a colspan 3

Comment: Looks like the only issue is with the size of the image. look at this http://jsfiddle.net/LucasCarioca/2te65yhv/

Comment: Well the size of the td that the img is in.